# innerHTML wont change if a changebox changes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a basic list:

```
<select id = "opt">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

Now I must change the selected items in JS. Its done, and then I need the content of this select items (`.innerHTML`).
But sadly, the innerHTML say nothing is selected... how to fix this?

EDIT: here is the code:

```
for (var count = 0; count < document.getElementById('opt').childNodes[0].options.length; count++)
{
 if (document.getElementById('opt').childNodes[0].options[count].value == 7) { document.getElementById('opt').childNodes[0].options[count].selected = true; break; }
}
var obj = document.getElementById('opt');
alert (obj.innerHTML);
```

and that `alert()` just displays the original HTML code

Comment: js code snippet will helps us to help you...

Comment: How do you change the selected items in JS? Post more code!

Comment: What do you want exactly ? What results do you expect ? What have you tried (code) ? What results did you get ? Your question is not enough accurate.

Comment: changebox? That is a new one.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as such

```
var opt = document.getElementById("opt");
var listLength = opt.options.length;
for(var i =0; i< listLength; i++) {
   if(opt.options[i].selected) {
      opt.options[i].textContent = 'the change HTML';
   }
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pEnsg/)

Comment: `option`-element can't have HTML. So there is no `innerHTML`-property for it. `innerText` or `textContent` are available.

Comment: @Teemu, Oops... Got caught up with OP I guess. Thanks Fixed it

Answer (score 2):

You might do this without using options at all.

just parse the nodes of the element

```
for (var count = 0; count < document.getElementById('opt').childNodes.length; count++)
{
    if (document.getElementById('opt').childNodes[count].value == "c") {       
        document.getElementById('opt').childNodes[count].selected = true; break; 
    }
}
var obj = document.getElementById('opt');
alert (obj.innerHTML);
```

​here it is your working jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9Pg8n/1/

Comment: ye, thats shows the problem. I select something, and the innerHTML say nothing is selected

Answer (score 0):

You can read text and value from the selected option like this:

```
var elem=document.getElementById('opt');
var value=elem[elem.selectedIndex].value;
var text=elem[elem.selectedIndex].text;
```

if you really need the HTML of the selected `option`-element:

```
var text=elem[elem.selectedIndex].outerHTML;
```

If  you peek `select`'s `innerHTML`, you can see `selected` attribute in IE, but it seems that other browsers don't reflect changes to the property. This stands for `option.outerHTML` too.

To fix this you need to set the attribute manually:

```
elem[elem.selectedIndex].setAttribute('selected','true');
```

However, this doesn't have an effect to the `innerHTML`-value in IE, thus you'll get slightly different HTML in other browsers.

```
<OPTION selected ...> // IE
<OPTION selected="true"...> // Other browsers
```

Unfortunately this set attribute remains, even when changing the selected element. So the attribute has to be removed after use:

```
elem[elem.selectedIndex].removeAttribute('selected');
```

But... this causes an issue in Chrome: it returns `-1` from `elem.selectedIndex`. You have to store the `selectedIndex` in the variable before setting the attribute, and then set the correct selection again:

```
elem[stored_index].selected=true;
```